# Local development with remote database hosted by meteor.com

Tags: meteor

I develop Meteor application on my local computer, and deploy it to meteor.com. I want to have an opportunity to use remote production MongoDB database for local development.

So, I get url to my DB with `meteor mongo --url myapp.meteor.com`, then I add it to my MONGO_URL environment variable:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://client-5345a08c:5f63edff-8cec-a818-7f35-c05021bb6d91@production-db-d1.meteor.io:27017/34377_ru
```

The inconvinience is that this url is invalid in one minute, so I need to generate another one and modify my `MONGO_URL` every time I want to start my application. I suspect some permanent url to my MongoDB is out there. I ran `meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com` and noticed greeting:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: production-db-d1.meteor.io:27017/34377_ru
```

I tried to use this url:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://production-db-d1.meteor.io:27017/34377_ru
```

and even

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://myneteorcomusername:mymeteorcompassproduction-db-d1.meteor.io:27017/34377_ru
```

but I had no luck.

Are there ways to simplify my workflow and make meteor use my remote database by default?

Answer (score 0):

I guess for scaling purposes, there is no dedicated mongo ever for each subdomain. I could be wrong so better ask this question over at the Meteor Talk Google group.